# Cant upload files to wasabi using AWSSDK.S3 3.7.305.*

Tags: amazon-s3, .net-core, wasabi

Some upstream dependencies were updated and its a little bit of a pain to revert them. When going from:

```
PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.S3" Version="3.7.204"
```

To:

```
PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.S3" Version="3.7.305.8"
```

I can no longer upload a file, I get the following error:

```
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
```

The code(example) being executed is as follows:

```
AmazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client(
      "access",
      "secret",
      new AmazonS3Config
      {
           AuthenticationRegion = RegionEndpoint.USEast1.SystemName,
           ServiceURL = "https://s3.wasabisys.com",
           ForcePathStyle = true, // Needed to work with Minio
           RetryMode = RequestRetryMode.Standard,
           MaxErrorRetry = 3
       });
string file = @"C:\Users\whaggerty\Documents\juryDuty.pdf";
string bucket = "default-2023-10";
string key = "juryDuty.pdf";



TransferUtilityUploadRequest uploadRequest = new()
{
    BucketName = bucket,
    Key = key,
    PartSize = 6291456, // 6 MB. (Same as FileService)
    FilePath = file,
};
using TransferUtility archiveUtility = new(client);
await archiveUtility.UploadAsync(uploadRequest);
```

Does anyone have any insight into what's causing this, and or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I needed to do was set the SignatureVersion to "2". I was messing around with that value last week but I thought I was supposed to use the SignatureVersion enum so I was doing it wrong. There are only two accepted values right now from what I can tell. "1" for SHA1 and "2" for SHA256.

```
AmazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client(
      "access",
      "secret",
      new AmazonS3Config
      {
           AuthenticationRegion = RegionEndpoint.USEast1.SystemName,
           ServiceURL = "https://s3.wasabisys.com",
           ForcePathStyle = true, // Needed to work with Minio
           RetryMode = RequestRetryMode.Standard,
           MaxErrorRetry = 3,
           SignatureVersion = "2"
   });
```